# Dark Nav Bar Icons?

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat

I want to use an Theme.AppCompat theme that uses dark nav bar icons as defaults, are there any Themes that do this? I can only see AppCompat.Light themes when I use the dot operator.

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat.Light is right because it means the color of the AppBar. If it's a light color, use light and the Icons and Texts will be black. If it's a dark color, use AppCompat and the Icons and Texts will be white.

Comment: I tried this and the Nav Bar icons are still white, is there a theme which will use dark nav bar icons as the default?

Comment: When I use AppCompat.Light, the navigation bar is black and navigation icons are white, I need a Theme where the navigation bar is light and the navigation icons are dark.